# cannot boot into ubuntu

Tags: boot, acer, cd

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 onto my Acer Aspire 5735Z. I have downloaded and burned the image to a CD (correctly as per your guide).
I have set my bios to boot CD first, disabled quite boot, tried switching from AHCI to IDE, etc.
nothing works.
I get to a "boot menu" where I select boot from CD. it then tells me "no operating system found"
I have tried everything on these forums as well as others.
Please help. I want to start using Ubuntu instead of windows but I am not getting very far.

Comment: I had this problem when I wanted to reinstall Ubuntu. Does the autorun appear when you're in Windows and you pop the CD in? If not, try to burn another CD or on a USB stick

Answer (score 0):

to me it sounds like your cd has a error that makes it unbootable.

Have you checked the cd or the download to see if it is corrupted? sometimes a the download can be corrupted check this website how to check for that:

[Ubuntu MD5 sum help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM.)

If the iso is correct you could try to burn it to a new cd. I always use a USB for my installations since it is re-usable see:

[Ubuntu usb installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)